# Picking 7 from a list.

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to pick out 7 from a list, here's my code:

```
(define (pick7 x)
  (cond ((null? x) x)
        ((= (car x) 7) pick7 (cdr x))
        (else (cons (car x) (pick7 (cdr x))))))
```

But when I call `(pick7 (1 3 (5 7) 9))`, it gives me an error.  I think I see the problem - the `(car x)` isn't always going to be a number, so I need to break it down.

How do I fix this?

Comment: `((= (car x) 7) pick7 (cdr x))` not doing what you think it does ;p (hint: missing parenthesis)

Comment: What's "picking"? you want to _delete_ all the 7s from a list of lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by pick out 7 from a list? Do you mean remove it? If so, you would also want to check if the first element is a list.

```
(define (pick7 x)
  (cond ((null? x) x)
        ((<??>) (cons (pick7 (car x)) (pick7 (cdr x))))
        ((= (car x) 7) (pick7 (cdr x)) ; missing paren
        (else (cons (car x) (pick7 (cdr x))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

If by "picking" you mean "removing" an element from a list, here's how you'd do it for a list of arbitrarily nested lists, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (pick7 x)
  (cond (<???> <???>)               ; if the list is null, return null
        ((not (pair? <???>))        ; if the first element is not a list
         (if <???>                  ;   if the first element is 7
             (pick7 <???>)          ;   advance recursion over rest of list
             (cons <???>            ;   else cons the first element and
                   (pick7 <???>)))) ;   advance recursion over rest of list
        (else (cons                 ; if the first element is a list, then cons
               (pick7 <???>)        ; the recursion over the first element
               (pick7 <???>)))))    ; and the recursion over the rest of list
```

Notice that this is the standard template for processing a list of arbitrarily nested lists, It will work for cases such as this:

```
(pick7 '(1 3 (5 7 (8 7 (10 7 11))) 9 7))
=> '(1 3 (5 (8 (10 11))) 9)
```